# Wxpython - remove tabs in application

Tags: python, tabs, wxpython

I have a application which I have previously been using multiple tabs. I have since changed the application and now only need a single panel. My issue is I can't seem to figure out how I get rid of the redundant tabs and revert to a single panel. Removing the `self.tabbed` in line 12 and 13 just result in a very odd looking panel, everything squashed to the corner. Below is the current tabbed code, I have removed lots of irrelevant code / classes, etc. What would be the most efficient way without effecting too much code?

UPDATE 1:

I have updated the below code, so it now runs.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui
import wx.stc as stc
import os
import platform
import time
systemType = platform.system()
if systemType == "Windows":
    import win32wnet

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        run_params = {}
        self.run_params = run_params

        # OS dependent info
        self.run_params["systemType"] = systemType
        if systemType == "Windows":
            self.run_params["fontSize"] = 8
            self.run_params["fontSize2"] = 7
        else:
            self.run_params["fontSize"] = 10
            self.run_params["fontSize2"] = 9

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(900, 710), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        style = aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE ^ aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB
        self.tabbed = aui.AuiNotebook(self, agwStyle=style)
        self.submissions = SubmissionPane(self.tabbed, self, run_params)

        self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.tabbed.AddPage(self.submissions, "TAB1")
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class SubmissionPane(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, frame, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.selected_folders = None
        self.params = run_params
        self.frame = frame

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.top_row_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL);
        radio_static_box = wx.StaticBox(self, label='Some Text')
        radio_static_box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(radio_static_box, wx.HORIZONTAL)

        job_static_box = wx.StaticBox(self, label='Some Text')
        job_static_box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(job_static_box, wx.HORIZONTAL)

        '''
        radio_labels = ['Some Text', 'Some Text2']
        self.radio_box = wx.RadioBox(
                self, -1, "", 
                choices=radio_labels,
        )
        '''
        self.radio1 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Some Text', style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.radio2 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Some Text')
        self.radio1.SetValue(True)

        radio_static_box_sizer.Add(self.radio1, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=0)
        radio_static_box_sizer.Add(self.radio2, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        self.top_row_sizer.Add(radio_static_box_sizer, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.check_box = wx.CheckBox(self, label="Some Text")
        self.check_box.SetValue(False)

        if self.params["systemType"] == "Windows":
            self.txtTitle = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, value="Some Text...", size=(200, -1), pos=(306, 14))
        else:
            self.txtTitle = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, value="Some Text...", size=(200, -1), pos=(350, 19))

        job_static_box_sizer.Add(self.check_box, flag=wx.LEFT, border=0)

        self.top_row_sizer.Add(job_static_box_sizer, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10);
        self.txtTitle.Show(False)

        main_sizer.Add(self.top_row_sizer);
        main_sizer.Add((-1, 10))

        job_static_box2 = wx.StaticBox(self, label='Some Text')

        third_row_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(job_static_box2, wx.HORIZONTAL);
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(375, 25))
        self.buttonGo = wx.Button(self, label='Go')
        self.buttonGo.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSubmit)
        third_row_sizer.Add(self.tc_files, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)

        if self.params["systemType"] == "Windows":
            third_row_sizer.Add(self.buttonGo, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=0)
        else:
            third_row_sizer.Add(self.buttonGo, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=2)

        main_sizer.Add(third_row_sizer, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.log_text22 = wx.ListCtrl(self,size=(875,275),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL | wx.LC_VRULES | wx.LC_HRULES)

        font = wx.Font(self.params["fontSize2"], wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)
        self.log_text22.SetFont(font)

        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(1, '1', width=40, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(2, '2', width=50, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(3, '3', width=156)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(4, '4', width=332)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(5, '5', width=100, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(6, '6', width=82, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(7, '7', width=60, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(8, '8', width=50, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)

        main_sizer.Add((-1, 10))
        list_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        list_sizer.Add(self.log_text22, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(list_sizer)

        self.running_log1 = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, -1, size=(875,175))
        self.running_log1.StyleSetFont(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, font)
        self.running_log1.SetMarginWidth(1, 0)
        self.running_log1.StyleSetBackground(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, (0,0,0))
        self.running_log1.StyleSetForeground(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, (0,255,0))
        self.running_log1.StyleClearAll()

        main_sizer.Add((-1, 5))
        list_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        list_sizer.Add(self.running_log1, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(list_sizer)

        list_sizer.Add((-1, 10))
        self.buttonClose = wx.Button(self, -1, "Quit")
        list_sizer.Add(self.buttonClose, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.SetBackgroundColour("Light Grey")

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        self.Show()

    def OnSubmit(self, event):
        msg = "Running"
        jobSubmitmsg = wx.BusyInfo(msg, self)
        time.sleep(3)
        jobSubmitmsg = None

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
MainWindow(None, -1, 'Application')
app.MainLoop()
```

UPDATE 2:

The below answer works very well.
Cheers.

Comment: Can you create a small runnable example? I can't get this one to run.

Comment: I have updated the question so the code now runs, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a Notebook at all, then you can just use the SubmissionPane itself and remove the aui stuff:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import os
import platform
import time
systemType = platform.system()
if systemType == "Windows":
    import win32wnet

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):

        run_params = {}
        self.run_params = run_params

        # OS dependent info
        self.run_params["systemType"] = systemType
        if systemType == "Windows":
            self.run_params["fontSize"] = 8
            self.run_params["fontSize2"] = 7
        else:
            self.run_params["fontSize"] = 10
            self.run_params["fontSize2"] = 9

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(900, 710), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        ##########################################################
        # Passed self here and removed the unnecessary second self
        ##########################################################
        self.submissions = SubmissionPane(self, run_params) 
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class SubmissionPane(wx.Panel):
    ################################################
    # changed the init here
    ################################################
    def __init__(self, parent, run_params):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.selected_folders = None
        self.params = run_params
        ################################################
        # changed the ref below
        ################################################
        self.frame = self  

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.top_row_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL);
        radio_static_box = wx.StaticBox(self, label='Some Text')
        radio_static_box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(radio_static_box, wx.HORIZONTAL)

        job_static_box = wx.StaticBox(self, label='Some Text')
        job_static_box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(job_static_box, wx.HORIZONTAL)

        '''
        radio_labels = ['Some Text', 'Some Text2']
        self.radio_box = wx.RadioBox(
                self, -1, "", 
                choices=radio_labels,
        )
        '''
        self.radio1 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Some Text', style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.radio2 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Some Text')
        self.radio1.SetValue(True)

        radio_static_box_sizer.Add(self.radio1, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=0)
        radio_static_box_sizer.Add(self.radio2, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        self.top_row_sizer.Add(radio_static_box_sizer, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.check_box = wx.CheckBox(self, label="Some Text")
        self.check_box.SetValue(False)

        if self.params["systemType"] == "Windows":
            self.txtTitle = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, value="Some Text...", size=(200, -1), pos=(306, 14))
        else:
            self.txtTitle = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, value="Some Text...", size=(200, -1), pos=(350, 19))

        job_static_box_sizer.Add(self.check_box, flag=wx.LEFT, border=0)

        self.top_row_sizer.Add(job_static_box_sizer, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10);
        self.txtTitle.Show(False)

        main_sizer.Add(self.top_row_sizer);
        main_sizer.Add((-1, 10))

        job_static_box2 = wx.StaticBox(self, label='Some Text')

        third_row_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(job_static_box2, wx.HORIZONTAL);
        self.tc_files = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(375, 25))
        self.buttonGo = wx.Button(self, label='Go')
        self.buttonGo.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSubmit)
        third_row_sizer.Add(self.tc_files, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)

        if self.params["systemType"] == "Windows":
            third_row_sizer.Add(self.buttonGo, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=0)
        else:
            third_row_sizer.Add(self.buttonGo, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP, border=2)

        main_sizer.Add(third_row_sizer, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.log_text22 = wx.ListCtrl(self,size=(875,275),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL | wx.LC_VRULES | wx.LC_HRULES)

        font = wx.Font(self.params["fontSize2"], wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)
        self.log_text22.SetFont(font)

        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(1, '1', width=40, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(2, '2', width=50, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(3, '3', width=156)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(4, '4', width=332)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(5, '5', width=100, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(6, '6', width=82, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(7, '7', width=60, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)
        self.log_text22.InsertColumn(8, '8', width=50, format=wx.LIST_FORMAT_CENTRE)

        main_sizer.Add((-1, 10))
        list_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        list_sizer.Add(self.log_text22, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(list_sizer)

        self.running_log1 = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self, -1, size=(875,175))
        self.running_log1.StyleSetFont(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, font)
        self.running_log1.SetMarginWidth(1, 0)
        self.running_log1.StyleSetBackground(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, (0,0,0))
        self.running_log1.StyleSetForeground(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, (0,255,0))
        self.running_log1.StyleClearAll()

        main_sizer.Add((-1, 5))
        list_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        list_sizer.Add(self.running_log1, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(list_sizer)

        list_sizer.Add((-1, 10))
        self.buttonClose = wx.Button(self, -1, "Quit")
        list_sizer.Add(self.buttonClose, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.TOP | wx.LEFT, border=10)

        self.SetBackgroundColour("Light Grey")

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        self.Layout()

    def OnSubmit(self, event):
        msg = "Running"
        jobSubmitmsg = wx.BusyInfo(msg, self)
        time.sleep(3)
        jobSubmitmsg = None

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
MainWindow(None, -1, 'Application')
app.MainLoop()
```